# Implementing jCounter

Tags: javascript, css

I have been trying to implement this page and I have set everything up except the jCounter. How do I change the event time? I tried looking up the jCounter page but that did not help. I'm a plain beginner so I hope you'll be able to help.

What I have tried:
Changing this part of the code:

> ```
> var settings = { 
>           'date': null,
>           'format': null
>       };
> ```

to a custom date and set the format to "on".

But I think the above settings is just to initialize the values with null value before beginning? If so where do I actually input the Event date to count down to? I have checked the index.html file and it just has the countdown.js call and the css applied to it, eventdate is never mentioned. So with these settings, the counter starts counting down from 198 days. I'm not sure where it's getting this event date from. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

This is the link for the tutorial for the counter: http://devingredients.com/2011/11/building-an-extensible-jquery-countdown-plugin-from-scratch/

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle link for this?

Comment: Yeah sure: http://jsfiddle.net/menxcg67/

Comment: Have a look at this Seahawks game schedule I made at the start of the season which counts down to all their game times  --  http://davealger.com/seahawks/  --  (I wish they had a better season)

Comment: Looks good DaveAlger. Could you take a look at the jsfiddle link above and tell me whether there is anything in there I can do to change the Event time?

Comment: what shoul be desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try the exact example from the documentation?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#countdown").countdown({
    date: "25 december 2014 1:00:00", // add the countdown's end date (i.e. 3 november 2012 12:00:00)
    format: "on" // on (03:07:52) | off (3:7:52) - two_digits set to ON maintains layout consistency
  },

  function() { 

    // the code here will run when the countdown ends
    alert("Santa on the roof!");

  });
});
```

try running the snippet below...

```js
(function($){

  $.fn.countDown = function (options) {
    config = {};

    $.extend(config, options);

    diffSecs = this.setCountDown(config);

    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' .digit').html('<div class="top"></div><div class="bottom"></div>');
    $(this).doCountDown($(this).attr('id'), diffSecs, 500);

    if (config.onComplete)
    {
      $.data($(this)[0], 'callback', config.onComplete);
    }
    if (config.omitWeeks)
    {
      $.data($(this)[0], 'omitWeeks', config.omitWeeks);
    }
    return this;

  };

  $.fn.stopCountDown = function () {
    clearTimeout($.data(this[0], 'timer'));
  };

  $.fn.startCountDown = function () {
    this.doCountDown($(this).attr('id'),$.data(this[0], 'diffSecs'), 500);
  };

  $.fn.setCountDown = function (options) {
    var targetTime = new Date();

    if (options.targetDate)
    {
      targetTime.setDate(options.targetDate.day);
      targetTime.setMonth(options.targetDate.month-1);
      targetTime.setFullYear(options.targetDate.year);
      targetTime.setHours(options.targetDate.hour);
      targetTime.setMinutes(options.targetDate.min);
      targetTime.setSeconds(options.targetDate.sec);
    }
    else if (options.targetOffset)
    {
      targetTime.setDate(options.targetOffset.day + targetTime.getDate());
      targetTime.setMonth(options.targetOffset.month + targetTime.getMonth());
      targetTime.setFullYear(options.targetOffset.year + targetTime.getFullYear());
      targetTime.setHours(options.targetOffset.hour + targetTime.getHours());
      targetTime.setMinutes(options.targetOffset.min + targetTime.getMinutes());
      targetTime.setSeconds(options.targetOffset.sec + targetTime.getSeconds());
    }

    var nowTime = new Date();

    diffSecs = Math.floor((targetTime.valueOf()-nowTime.valueOf())/1000);

    $.data(this[0], 'diffSecs', diffSecs);

    return diffSecs;
  };

  $.fn.doCountDown = function (id, diffSecs, duration) {
    $this = $('#' + id);
    if (diffSecs <= 0)
    {
      diffSecs = 0;
      if ($.data($this[0], 'timer'))
      {
        clearTimeout($.data($this[0], 'timer'));
      }
    }

    secs = diffSecs % 60;
    mins = Math.floor(diffSecs/60)%60;
    hours = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60)%24;
    if ($.data($this[0], 'omitWeeks') == true)
    {
      days = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60/24);
      weeks = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60/24/7);
    }
    else 
    {
      days = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60/24)%7;
      weeks = Math.floor(diffSecs/60/60/24/7);
    }

    $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'seconds_dash', secs, duration ? duration : 800);
    $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'minutes_dash', mins, duration ? duration : 1200);
    $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'hours_dash', hours, duration ? duration : 1200);
    $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'days_dash', days, duration ? duration : 1200);
    $this.dashChangeTo(id, 'weeks_dash', weeks, duration ? duration : 1200);

    $.data($this[0], 'diffSecs', diffSecs);
    if (diffSecs > 0)
    {
      e = $this;
      t = setTimeout(function() { e.doCountDown(id, diffSecs-1) } , 1000);
      $.data(e[0], 'timer', t);
    } 
    else if (cb = $.data($this[0], 'callback')) 
    {
      $.data($this[0], 'callback')();
    }

  };

  $.fn.dashChangeTo = function(id, dash, n, duration) {
    $this = $('#' + id);
    d2 = n%10;
    d1 = (n - n%10) / 10

    if ($('#' + $this.attr('id') + ' .' + dash))
    {
      $this.digitChangeTo('#' + $this.attr('id') + ' .' + dash + ' .digit:first', d1, duration);
      $this.digitChangeTo('#' + $this.attr('id') + ' .' + dash + ' .digit:last', d2, duration);
    }
  };

  $.fn.digitChangeTo = function (digit, n, duration) {
    if (!duration)
    {
      duration = 800;
    }
    if ($(digit + ' div.top').html() != n + '')
    {
      $(digit + ' div.top').css({'display': 'none'});
      $(digit + ' div.top').html((n ? n : '0')).slideDown(duration);
      $(digit + ' div.bottom').animate({'height': ''}, duration, function() {
        $(digit + ' div.bottom').html($(digit + ' div.top').html());
        $(digit + ' div.bottom').css({'display': 'block', 'height': ''});
        $(digit + ' div.top').hide().slideUp(10);


      });
    }
  };
  
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cd_1').countDown({
      targetDate: {
        'day':   25,
        'month':  12,
        'year':  2014,
        'hour':  20,
        'min':   25,
        'sec':   0,
        'utc':    true
      }, omitWeeks: true
    });
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  background: #ddd;
  min-width: 340px;
  min-height: 80px;
}

.countdown_dashboard {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #444;
}

.title {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #002244;
}

.lbl {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #666;
}

.pad {
padding-right: 30px;
}

.row img {
  padding: 18px 8px 0 0;
}

.dash {
  height: 14px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.dash .digit {
  background: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  font-size: 30px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 6px 0 0;
  padding: 7px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="title">&nbsp;&nbsp;According to the <a href="http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/326240">data</a>, you will die from ebola in...</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="card">
  <table>
    <tr class="row">
      <td><img src="http://davealger.com/ebola/virus.png" width="80" /></td>
      <td style="vertical-align:top;padding-top:10px;padding-right:20px;">
        <div id="cd_1" class="countdown_dashboard">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td class="lbl">days</td>
              <td class="lbl">hours</td>
              <td class="lbl">mins</td>
              <td class="lbl">secs</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="dash days_dash">
                  <div class="digit"></div>
                  <div class="digit"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="dash hours_dash">
                  <div class="digit"></div>
                  <div class="digit"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="dash minutes_dash">
                  <div class="digit"></div>
                  <div class="digit"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="dash seconds_dash">
                  <div class="digit"></div>
                  <div class="digit"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, this worked. I can't believe I missed this. I used the code that came with the template, it did not have this function written in for some reason. Thanks a lot ^_^